# Failsafe html reports in Jenkins

Tags: html, maven, selenium, jenkins, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have some integration tests (with Selenium) which are run with failsafe maven plugin. Failsafe generates XML reports files only.

1) I want to generate HTML reports

2) I want to have a link in Jenkins to the html reports

For the 1) I installed the "maven-surefire-report-plugin" to use the failsafe-report-only goal.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.13</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>failsafe-report-only</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But in the standard output, nothing seems to be generated :

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.13:failsafe-report-only (default) @ BaseContrats >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.13:failsafe-report-only (default) @ BaseContrats <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-report-plugin:2.13:failsafe-report-only (default) @ BaseContrats ---
```

In my failsafe-reports directory, I have only XML report files but not the HTML ones.

Is it the good plugin to generate html reports for failsafe?

For the 2), I installed the Jenkins plugin "Selenium HTML report" and added the post build action "Publish Selenium HTML report" and configured it with "target/failsafe-reports" value for "Selenium tests results location" parameter, but nothing is displayed in Jenkins interface (surely because my html reports file are not generated...).

Could you help me for these 2 points?

Comment: I think the Maven "site" plugin will generate HTML reports for you want them, right?  Either that or I do know that jenkins can do it as long as you set the Junit plugin filter to locate the test output files in the right location.

Answer (score 6):

Answer for the part 1) to generate HTML reports for Failsafe.

Add the following to pom.xml

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipSurefireReport>${skipSurefireReport}</skipSurefireReport>
                <reportsDirectories>
                    <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/target/failsafe-reports</reportsDirectory>
                </reportsDirectories>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<properties>
   <skipSurefireReport>true</skipSurefireReport>
</properties>
```

I am assuming you are using mvn verify to run the integration tests using failsafe-plugin.
By default, this generates the (`*.txt` & `*.xml`) reports in {basedir}/target/failsafe-reports. This should be specified in `<reportDirectories>`. You can point to any directory which has TEST-*.xml reports.

And then run the cmd

```
mvn site
```

This would generate html reports for the Failsafe run integration tests. By default, The files would be in {basedir}/target/site/failsafe-report.html.
This location be changed.